# Prove that matrix is invertible by knowing that other matrix is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let `A, B` be matrices of the order `nxn`,
Prove that if `AB^2-A` is invertible, so `BA-A` is also invertible.

How can I prove that without using determinants?

Thanks!

Comment: Since $AB^2-A$ is invertible, if you factorise it as a product of three matrices $X,Y$ and $Z$, these three matrices must be invertible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A(B^2 - I)=A(B-I)(B+I)$ is invertible, so all three factors are invertible.

You need to know that $AB$ is invertible iff $A$ and $B$ are both invertible. One implication follows from $(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1} A^{-1}$ and the other from $A\big(B(AB)^{-1}\big)=I$ etc.